# Generics and use of 'instanceof'

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

A question specific to generics in Java, and their usage with `instanceof`:

For the following if-statement: `if (((NodeInternal<Value>) parent).NW() instanceof NodeLeaf<?>)`

I need this cast in order to access the `parent`'s `NW`. `NW` is a property of `parent` which is of type `NodeInternal`.

I need to check if the reference pointer held by `NW` is an instance of `NodeLeaf<?>`. A runtime error is produced: `NodeLeaf cannot be cast to NodeInternal`. This is because leaf is cast as an internal, however, the cast should be only for `parent` to be able to access `NW()`.

How would I fix such a problem?

Thank you

Comment: Well, the error you're getting suggests that the type of `parent` is not, in fact, `NodeInternal`. We'd need to see more code to be certain.

Comment: The simplest explanation seems to be that you have a bug and `parent instanceof NodeLead<?>` is true.  How did you rule that out?

Comment: I would have to agree that `parent` is a `NodeLeaf`.

Comment: Yep that was the case! I got parent to be an instance of NodeInternal, fixed it. Thanks guys. You can add an answer below and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I commented first so I'll do the honors :)

The explanation is that `parent` is in fact of class `NodeLeaf` and not `NodeInternal`.